# Using strcmp with two dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I asked a question a while ago and as a result of the answers I received I revised my program significantly. I am having trouble now though using the strcmp method with a two dimensional array. Here is the gist of my program:

I am trying to write a program that checks to see if a word inputed to a program matches one of the predefined keywords. Input is going to be coming from a text file and the text file will have a single word in it. So far the text file I have just has the word 'dog' which means the program should clearly print 'Match Found!' but it in fact prints 'No Match Found' It prints 'Match Found' when the word in the text file is 'crackerjack' which suggests it is not checking each word in the keywords array, just the first word. Here is my code, does anything stand out to you guys? Thanks

```
#define NUM 4
#define SIZE 12

int isAlpha(char);

//Returns 1 if it is an Alphabetical character, 0 if it is not
int isAlpha(char c) {
  return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z' || c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}

int main() {
  char message[141];
  int charCount = 0, c = 0, matchCheck = 0, anyMatch = 0;

  char keywords[NUM][SIZE] = {
    "crackerjack",
    "hey",
    "dog",
    "feet"
  };

  //Removes non alphabetical characters
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF && charCount <= 140) {
    if(isAlpha(c)){
      message[charCount] = c;
      charCount++;
    }
  }

  //checks if message matches keyword
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
      if(strcmp(message, keywords[i]) == 0){
        matchCheck = 1;
        break; 
      }
  }  

  //prints "Match Found!" if there was a match
  if (matchCheck == 1)
    printf("Match Found!\n");
  else 
    printf("No Match Found\n");

return(0);

}
```

Comment: use `strncmp` instead of `strcmp`

Comment: `strncmp(message, keywords[i], charCount)` would work, but it's better to NUL-terminate `message`.

Comment: @Lundin strncmp isn't so bad, and isn't obsolete (there is no strncmp_s); it's strncpy that's a disaster. (Your link is about cat and cpy, not cmp).

Comment: @JimBalter Gah, yes indeed. I don't know what I was thinking when I posted that, thanks for correcting. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`message`, the input to `strcmp`, isn't terminated by a `\0`. Do it right after the loop like this

```
#include <ctype.h>
while((c = getchar()) != EOF && charCount <= 140) {
  if(isalpha((unsigned char)c)){
    message[charCount++] = c;
  }
}
message[charCount++] = '\0';
```

Another way to do it is to initialize `message` to all zeros like this `char messasge[141] = {0};`, so that you don't have to bother terminating it in the end like above. As an aside, `keywords` can be defined without requiring `NUM` or `SIZE` thus:

```
const char* keywords[] = {
    "crackerjack",
    "hey",
    "dog",
    "feet"
};
```

However, if you need to change the contents of `keywords` at run-time, you should do it as `char keywords[][SIZE] = { ... };`.

Thanks to Jim for bringing this up as a comment. Instead of using your own `isAlpha`, you should you the standard library function `isalpha` which takes an `int` but has defined behaviour only for the range of `unsigned char`, thus typecast your input and passing it to `isalpha` should do. However, if your input can be beyond 256 then you should handle it differently.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can now continue for with my program, you helped me overcome a problem which I was really struggling with. Very grateful!

Comment: @user2817587 Usually one writes `char* keywords[] = { ... }`, eliminating the need for `SIZE` as well.

Comment: While you're at it, you could use `isalpha` from `<ctype.h>` as well. :-) (Watch out for UB with negative args, though.) (And, yeah, `const` is good too; +1)

Comment: I don't understand your added last line ... changes can be made by replacing the pointers. I suppose it depends on what sort of changes would be made. If keywords are going to be added, the list needs to be malloced.

Comment: @JimBalter: I meant changing the actual string, which shouldn't be done if it were declared as a pointer since the string would be allocated in `.rodata` i.e. read-only memory. That's the reason I augmented it with a `const`.

Comment: Right, I know you meant that, but as I said you can just replace the pointer with one to a different string -- a much better approach than changing the content of a fixed size char array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't NUL-terminate `message`. It contains junk on the stack, probably with a non-NUL somewhere past the first 3 chars, and that non-NUL gets overwritten when you read "crackerjack" but not when you read "dog".

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your message character array to `0`.
`strcmp()` need this so that it can compare two strings (it needs to know where the string is terminated).

So change:

```
char message[141];
```

to

```
char message[141] = {0};
```

Other than this change your keywords definition to:

```
char *keywords[NUM] = {
    "crackerjack",
    "hey",
    "dog",
    "feet"
  };
```

Comment: 0 is not NULL. NULL is not string null termination.